# Client server on external ip's and different networks android

Tags: android, client, server

I wrote a client server application that works only on the same network.
Is it possible for a client implemented using sockets to connect to a server's external ip (also implemented using sockets..) and/or on different networks?
I used to think its possible, but Its just not working...
I'm telling the client to connect to my server by giving him the server's ip.
but the client's socket gets null `socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work, the problem will be with networking rather than Android or Sockets. You should make sure that the firewall in front of your server is letting through your port and forwarding the port to your server's internal ip address.

Comment: you could try [portmapper](https://github.com/kaklakariada/portmapper) - a Java lib that lets you open ports if you have a compatible UPnP router. I don't think that's what you want though because it has to be run from inside the server's network (so by the server). That's just a Java implementation - I'm sure you can find an equivalent for whatever language you made the server in.